# Setting a breakpoint inside Wine's source code

Tags: c, debugging, gdb, wine

I've downloaded and built Wine from source. Now I want to use a debugger to debug a certain function - `BitBlt()`. The problem is, that it doesn't seem to see the source code. As you can see, when I type 'l', it can't see my source code.

```
sashoalm@homepc:~$ winedbg /tmp/bitblttest.exe 
WineDbg starting on pid 0022
0x7b863444 DbgBreakPoint+0x4 in kernel32: popl  %ebp
Wine-dbg>break BitBlt
Breakpoint 1 at 0x7ebb5501 BitBlt in gdi32
Wine-dbg>cont
Stopped on breakpoint 1 at 0x7ebb5501 BitBlt in gdi32
Wine-dbg>list
Enter path to file '' (<cr> to end search):
```

I've compiled Wine using `./configure`, `make`, and `make install`, no special arguments given to `./configure`.

What should I change, so I can see the source code?

Answer (score 1):

I think that you have to export CFLAGS=-g and CXXFLAGS=-g prior to running ./configure.  In addition I believe you have to have a copy of the source code in the current working directory when you are running or debugging.  I know this cannot hurt.  As a side note debugging painting code is notoriously hard has when a break point hits the screen likely will need to repaint itself winding up in infinite loops.

gdi32 may be a windows library that you don't have source for.  Half of this exercise is using Windows calls and may also be difficult to debug.

Comment: is gdi32 a windows or compiled library?